# Split array-like string values in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework, calculated-field

A field in my data is stored as a string instead of a real nested array:

```
{
  "uuid": "yxcvb", 
  "product": "[{\"pid\":\"4f76c06825aa486db9a7a5cedbc2ea19\",\"size\":\"S\"},{\"pid\":\"d3055e0a1bb040dba65674b9733bf4ce\",\"size\":\"M\"}]",
  "timestamp":{"$date":"2023-01-01T11:25:47+00:00"}
},
{
  "uuid": "asdfg", 
  "product": "[{\"pid\":\"369b33cc768d496193b18d657d706920\",\"size\":\"M\"}]",
  "timestamp":{"$date":"2023-01-02T11:25:47+00:00"}
},
{
  "uuid": "qwert", 
  "product": "[{\"pid\":\"13325cb71fd7413c8f3e18caf20b5d6d\",\"size\":\"S\"},{\"pid\":\"ac431397d49d449cab44d98dc13ec57c\",\"size\":\"M\"},{\"pid\":\"ba35b9f804a44e15bf197d3ef671dc34\",\"size\":\"L\"}]",
  "timestamp":{"$date":"2023-01-03T11:25:47+00:00"}
}

/// "product" has a maximum of 4 dict-like pid-size units
```

I would like to know the count of each `size` and group by `timestamp`. Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "week": 52,
    "sizeS": 1
  },
  {
    "week": 52,
    "sizeM": 1
  },
  {
    "week": 1,
    "sizeS": 1
  },
  {
    "week": 1,
    "sizeM": 2
  },
  {
    "week": 1,
    "sizeL": 1
  }
]
```

To realize this, the following problems need to be solved:

1. Turn the array-like string into a real string, then I could use `$unwind`.
2. If 1 cannot be achieved, extract all `pid` and `size` values in a document, and save only the value after the colon (e.g. "4f76c06825aa486db9a7a5cedbc2ea19", "M").
3. After 2, count total records of each `size` within the grouped timeframe (week).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$function` to parse the json strings and use it as normal mongodb fields.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "product": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(product) {return JSON.parse(product)}",
          "args": [
            "$product"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$product"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        week: {
          "$isoWeek": "$timestamp"
        },
        size: "$product.size"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.week": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WcBbXJEBpyS)

Comment: Wow, thank you! This looks like a super helpful function!

Comment: @TMPS actually not. In the [official doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) it explicitly stated that it has performance impact. Consider avoid storing json text in your schema if possible

Comment: Okay, I have already encountered a problem. I tried to use the query directly in MongoDB Chart, but got an error: (JSInterpreterFailure) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @TMPS you are probably having invalid json data for some documents. That is why you should avoid storing json text in your schema as it is very error prone. Try to find such documents and update your question(or even ask a new question) to see what we can do about it.